# Can not access to samba4.1 shares on gentoo box

Tags: samba, gentoo

I have one Windows 7 x64 PC, and a Gentoo Box, which act as a NAS. I tried to migrate from Samba3 to Samba4.1.6, and while Samba isup, I fail to connect; I have the following error that is popping (it worked on Samba 3).

```
[18:24:35.494397,3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:177(auth_check_ntlm_password)  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [WindowsHost]\[WindowsUser]@[WindowsHost] with the new password interface
[18:24:35.494421,3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:180(auth_check_ntlm_password)  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [GentooBox]\[GentooUser]@[WindowsHost]
[18:24:35.494645,3] ../source3/passdb/lookup_sid.c:1560(get_primary_group_sid)  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for GentooUser
[18:24:35.494908,3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:226(auth_check_ntlm_password)  check_ntlm_password: sam authentication for user [WindowsUser] succeeded
[18:24:35.495065,2] ../source3/auth/pampass.c:577(smb_pam_account)  smb_pam_account: PAM: There was an authentication error for user GentooUser
[18:24:35.495088,2] ../source3/auth/pampass.c:89(smb_pam_error_handler)  smb_pam_error_handler: PAM: Account Check Failed : Authentication failure
[18:24:35.495168,0] ../source3/auth/pampass.c:797(smb_pam_accountcheck)  smb_pam_accountcheck: PAM: Account Validation Failed - Rejecting User GentooUser!
[18:24:35.495240,3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:268(auth_check_ntlm_password)  check_ntlm_password:  PAM Account for user [GentooUser] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
[18:24:35.495269,2] ../auth/gensec/spnego.c:743(gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg)  SPNEGO login failed: NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
[18:24:35.495625,3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:212(exit_server_common)  Server exit (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

I might not have understood it well, but is that still possible to configure Samba without AD, LDAP and simply accept, that Windows user is Linux user, only based on password information ?

--

My conf is the following :

```
[global]
        workgroup = WHITE_SPACE
        server string = WHITE SPACE
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        guest account = smbconsu
        username map = /etc/samba/users.map
        log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
        max log size = 1000
        load printers = No
        dns proxy = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        hosts allow = 192.168.113., 127.0.0.1
        hosts deny = ALL
        log level=3
[animes]
        comment = Animes Repository
        path = /mnt/raid5/samba/animes
        valid users = +smbshare
        write list = GentooUser
        guest ok = Yes
        case sensitive = No
```

And the users.map :

```
GentooUser = "WindowsHost/WindowsUser" "WindowsUser"
smbconsu = guest pcguest smbguest
```